# Ubuntu Studio Real Time Scan Antivirus

Tags: antivirus

Is there some real time scan antivirus software for ubuntu studio?

Where?

Well, I know the typical answer: "It is very hard to find a virus to Linux."

The problem is to all of those people (like me) that still have to use some Windows OS software.

This is because there aren't some Linux software to replace some Windows software (for example, my case about a radio automation package).

Greetings & Blessings from Chile!!!

Juan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this command

```
sudo apt-get install clamtk
```

Other closed source virus scanning exists, but I personally do not promote or use them.  If you want to check it out look at the Sophos website.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I'll use it, even the fact that it doesn't perform any kind of real time scan for virus, but... Something is better than nothing!!!

Comment: A lot of programs allow you to put commands into specific actions.  For example Thunderbird allows you to run a command when getting new emails.  You can also setup a cron job, or a boot up script that will run and perform your commands.

Comment: Where can I get a full guide to learn how to perform all those actions? ???

Comment: I think it depends on which one of those things you wanna do, but I think you would have to break those things up and search them.  Also search AskUbuntu for sure and if you find nothing just make another question about it.  Either myself or some other helpful user will help you out.

Comment: Something is wrong, here! It is supposed that clamtk put a "Search for threats" into the files manager menu option, but it didn't, there isn't some antivirus option on those menu. Also, I scheduled an auto analysis at 21:00, today, now it's 22:00 and... Nothing is happen! What's wrong with clamtk? ???

Comment: I  don't have anything in my context menu, but if I type "clamtk" I can start the application and then in the menu I can select "Scan" -> "A Directory" and then just select the directory I want to scan.  Clamtk is just a gui application for clamav.  clamav is the actual program that does the scanning.  If you do a "man clamscan" you can also look at it that way.